# react native how to get the people details or App invite Referral shared through ShareVia all apps API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
shareClick() {
const result=https: //play.google.com/apps/testing/com.birdietest/adityamas234;
const { navigate, state: { params } } = this.props.navigation;
AsyncStorage.getItem('referal', (err, result) => {
Share.share({
message: result,
url: result,
// title: `${params.name}`
}, {
// Android only:
dialogTitle: 'Share BAM goodness',
// iOS only:
excludedActivityTypes: [
'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'
]
})
this.setState({
ref: result
})
console.log(result);
});

}
```

I am sharing the play store link to other users via share via all options API.

[Here is the Screenshot of exactly How I needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXzhA.png)

So, How can I can I know people Who installed my application by clicking on my link i.e I can see the list of people who installed the application using my link.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: You can use a website like bit.ly and share their custom url and they will count your clicks plus different information like region etc..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I use bit.ly with ReactNative? It is showing only number of clicks. How to get the people who installed my application

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the people who installed your application" ? What information you want to get? And with bit.ly you just replace your `result` url with the one you generated with bitly.